# TeXstudio does not run after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit to Ubuntu 16.04. When I run TeXstudio now from terminal, I am getting the following error message:

`$ texstudio 
texstudio: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt5.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN13GfxColorSpace17getDisplayProfileEv`

It seems some qt5 libraries are messed. Any ideas?

Extra info (for qt4-based texstudio dependencies related to `libpoppler*`):

`$ ldd /usr/bin/texstudio
... 
libpoppler-qt4.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt4.so.4 (0x00007fb62c61c000)
...
libpoppler.so.58 => /usr/local/lib/libpoppler.so.58 (0x00007fb6292a8000)
...`

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling texstudio?

Comment: Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/716506/lots-of-symbol-lookup-errors-in-dynamically-linked-libraries). If no luck, in case you installed TeXstudio from Ubuntu repositories, uninstall it, run `sudo apt autoremove` and download & install from http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#download (I prefer the Qt4 version).

Comment: @alwaysask Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, your first idea is not so clear to me. Which files do I have to remove? The second idea gives me new error message: `$ sudo dpkg -i texstudio-qt4_2.11.0_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for vl: 
(Reading database ... 806694 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack texstudio-qt4_2.11.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking texstudio-qt4 (2.11.0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive texstudio-qt4_2.11.0_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texstudio/template_Moderncv.json'
`

Comment: First thing I suggested is to look for symlinks or lib files where that link says on your system. As for your install error, did you uninstall the old TeXstudio version prior to installing the new version?

Comment: @alwaysask It seems  although I already did `sudo apt autoremove` before, I had to do it once again. This time I have not had any problems with the `texstudio-qt4_2.11.0_amd64.deb` installation. However when I am trying to run the texstudio, there is new error message: `texstudio: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt4.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZN13GfxColorSpace17getDisplayProfileEv`

Comment: There are some issues with the Qt libraries on your system, probably from something your tried to install, didn't work and improperly fixed it. Unfortunately this is offtopic on TeX.SX. Try finding a solution from [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=qt+%22symbol+lookup+error%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the suggestions from @alwaysask, the [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/115970) and [discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/115970/comments/26) helped me to figure out what I have to do.

I moved all `poppler` related files from `/usr/local/lib` to temporary user directory ( `/home/vl/software/lib` ) like

`sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libpoppler* /home/vl/software/lib`

and after that the texstudio (qt4-based package: `texstudio-qt4_2.11.0_amd64.deb` ) is successfully running again!!!

Comment: This is what my first suggestion link said in the reply there - improperly/wrongly placed libs (or symlinks to them) in the `/usr/local/lib` folder :) Glad you finally worked it out.

Comment: @alwaysask I agree, you gave me the right direction. Many thanks! The case in the [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/716506/lots-of-symbol-lookup-errors-in-dynamically-linked-libraries) is similar but the answer is not so evident because I did not know which files I have to re/move.

Comment: Well, the keywords there are "package manager doesn't put any libraries there". In the `/usr/local/lib` folder there should be no files (let alone files with *lib* in their name), only folders. For example, on my system: `ls /usr/local/lib` shows 2 python folders and the `x86_64-linux-gnu` folder. So make sure there are no other files in there (move them elsewhere if they are, same as you did with the libpoppler ones), otherwise some other errors mght pop up when least expected and in a hurry.

Comment: @alwaysask Your brief explanation sounds very clear now and deserves putting it into wiki page or you may want to convert it to an answer and post it here. Anyway, I am ready to upvote it! PS. My computer has passed several upgrades (12.04 -> 14.04 -> 16.04) and many installations so that I am not so surprised seeing such 'unwanted' files.